# How can I tell Sentry not to alert certain exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sentry

I have a Rails 5 application using [raven-ruby](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby) to send exceptions to Sentry which then sends alerts to our Slack.

```
Raven.configure do |config|
  config.dsn = ENV['SENTRY_DSN']
  config.environments = %w[ production development ]
  config.excluded_exceptions += []
  config.async = lambda { |event|
    SentryWorker.perform_async(event.to_hash)
  }
end

class SentryWorker < ApplicationWorker
  sidekiq_options queue: :default

  def perform(event)
    Raven.send_event(event)
  end
end
```

It's normal for our Sidekiq jobs to throw exceptions and be retried. These are mostly intermittent API errors and timeouts which clear up on their own in a few minutes. Sentry is dutifully sending these false alarms to our Slack.

I've already [added the `retry_count` to the jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065578/sidekiq-retry-count-in-job). How can I prevent Sentry from sending exceptions with a retry_count < N to Slack while still alerting for other exceptions? An example that should not be alerted will have extra context like this:

```
sidekiq: {
  context: Job raised exception,
  job: {
    args: [{...}],
    class: SomeWorker,
    created_at: 1540590745.3296254,
    enqueued_at: 1540607026.4979043,
    error_class: HTTP::TimeoutError,
    error_message: Timed out after using the allocated 13 seconds,
    failed_at: 1540590758.4266324,
    jid: b4c7a68c45b7aebcf7c2f577,
    queue: default,
    retried_at: 1540600397.5804272,
    retry: True,
    retry_count: 2
  },
}
```

What are the pros and cons of not sending them to Sentry at all vs sending them to Sentry but not being alerted?

Comment: I think what you want is to monitor how often this error occurs overall anyway, not if it still happens after the nth retry.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer How often it happens overall is why I want to keep sending them to Sentry, but not get alerted. I don't have control over how flakey the APIs are. I just have to compensate for that. One or two retries for a job is normal. At five we want to investigate.

Comment: I posted two workarounds for this. I'm not entirely sure if they're a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sidekiq retry count in job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065578/sidekiq-retry-count-in-job)

Comment: This is not part of the worker class on purpose: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/845
Use a client middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065578/sidekiq-retry-count-in-job and https://medium.com/appaloosa-store-engineering/make-a-failing-sidekiq-worker-call-a-method-after-a-specific-number-of-retries-709d7f2cb9f3

Comment: @LukasEklund I've already added the retry_count, thank you. The issue is more about Sentry than Sidekiq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out the entire event if the retry_count is < N (can be done inside that sidekiq worker you posted). You will loose the data on how often this happens without alerting, but the alerts themselves will not be too noisy.

```
class SentryWorker < ApplicationWorker
  sidekiq_options queue: :default

  def perform(event)
    retry_count = event.dig(:extra, :sidekiq, :job, retry_count)
    if retry_count.nil? || retry_count > N
      Raven.send_event(event)
    end
  end
end
```

Another idea is to set a different fingerprint depending on whether this is a retry or not. Like this:

```
class MyJobProcessor < Raven::Processor
  def process(data)
    retry_count = event.dig(:extra, :sidekiq, :job, retry_count)
    if (retry_count || 0) < N
      data["fingerprint"] = ["will-retry-again", "{{default}}"]
    end
  end
end
```

See https://docs.sentry.io/learn/rollups/?platform=javascript#custom-grouping

I didn't test this, but this should split up your issues into two, depending on whether sidekiq will retry them. You can then ignore one group but can still look at it whenever you need the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get what the processor is doing. What should I do on the Sentry side?

Comment: @Schwern I don't understand the question. Are you asking for clarification on the last sentence?

Comment: I understand that it's adding a fingerprint, though I'm not entirely sure what that does. I can't find how I use that fingerprint to control the alerts on Sentry. https://sentry.io/settings/<team>/<project>/alerts/rules/new/ I have `An event's tags match {key} {comparison} {value}` so maybe I can add `will-retry` as a tag.

Comment: Sure, you can also add it as a tag and use the tag to configure the alert. I guess that's a better idea.

With the fingerprint you'd get a separate issue you can just mute. No alert configuration.

Comment: I think I see now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

**Summary**

An option that has worked well for me is by configuring [Sentry's `should_capture`](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/ruby/config/) alongside Sidekiq's [`sidekiq_retries_exhausted`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration) with a custom attribute on the exception.

**Details**

1a. Add the custom attribute

You can add a custom attribute to an exception. You can define this on any error class with `attr_accessor`:

```
class SomeError
  attr_accessor :ignore

  alias ignore? ignore
end
```

1b. Rescue the error, set the custom attribute, & re-raise

```
def perform
  # do something
rescue SomeError => e
  e.ignore = true
  raise e
end
```

2. Configure `should_capture`

`should_capture` allows you to capture exceptions when they meet a defined criteria. The exception is passed to it, on which you can access the custom attribute.

`config.should_capture { |e| !e.ignore? }`

3. Flip the custom attribute when retries are exhausted

There are 2 ways to define the behaviour you want to happen when a job dies, depending on the version of Sidekiq being used. If you want to apply globally & have sidekiq v5.1+, you can use a [death handler](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#death-notification). If you want to apply to a particular worker or have less than v5.1, you can use `sidekiq_retries_exhausted`.

`sidekiq_retries_exhausted  { |_job, ex| ex.ignore = false }`

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the exception doesn't have an `ignore=` method. ` NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `ignore='`

Comment: @Maros I added a code example and further explanation to my answer. You can set an `attr_accessor` on your error class (or on StandardError).

Comment: But what if the error is defined by a library? I'd have to monkey patch it right

Answer (score 3):

A much cleaner approach if you are trying to ignore exceptions belonging to a certain class is to add them to your config file

```rb
config.excluded_exceptions += ['ActionController::RoutingError', 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound']
```

In the above example, the exceptions Rails uses to generate 404 responses will be suppressed.

[See the docs for more configuration options](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/configuration/options/)

Comment: Thank you, but the question is about conditionally excluding exceptions, not whole classes of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the best option is Sentry holds all the exceptions and you could modify Sentry and set alerts to send or not the exceptions to the Slack.
In order to configure the Alerts in Sentry: In the sentry account, you could go to the ALerts option in the main menu.

In the following picture I configure an alert to only send to slack a notification if occurs an Exception of type ControllerException more than 10 times

[image: Configure alert in sentry]

Using this alert we only receive the notification in Slack when all conditions are accomplished